Index Lookup in Azure Promptflow
Is there a way where I can specify the output for the index lookup tool? I know that the deprecated VectorDB Lookup tool had a 'search_params' field whoch allowed the user to specify the fields to return. Can I acheive a similar result with index lookup?
I am new to Azure Promptflow, and have been working on implementing an image similarity search. This is what I have done so far:

Prepared a repository of images

Used GPT4-Vision to generate a textual description of each image

Created an excel file with the filename and description as pairs

Created a vector index with the excel file

Created a flow that takes in a single word as input, and passes it as a query input to the index lookup tool


However, while it does seem to work. I am unable to access the filename for which the lookup tool outputs.
